# Jquery select attribute and insert another attribute to the element

Tags: jquery, select, attributes, insert

Would appreciate if somebody could help me with something like this:

NOTE!:

> I Do not have any class or IDs the title itself is what I use to
>   select the element

Example: `<a title="name"></a>`

Insert a attribute into the element so it looks like this:

```
<a title="name" onclick=""></a>
```

I want to insert this into the onclick=`'onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', '', '', '']);'`

But I'm out of luck, anyone knows how to bind the '' with multiple '' inside?

Comment: Think you are missing one or two details in the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

```
$('a[title="name"]').attr('onclick', '');
```

But rather than mess with the `onclick` attribute, you should just bind a click handler.

```
$('a[title="name"]').click(function() { alert('You clicked the button'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('a[title="name"]').attr('onclick', '')`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').attr('onclick', 'code here');
```

[jQuery attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

[Here's it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/HJJjE/)

Answer (score 0):

$('a').attr('onClick', 'insert code here');

Answer (score 0):

I guess your sentence was not finished, but I would recommend to check the attr() selector (and function) in jQuery : http://api.jquery.com/attr/

- attr() lets you get the properties of an element : $("#id").attr("value");
- attr() also lets you modifiy attributes in elements if you set a value as second parameter : $("#id").attr("value", "whatever");

You can also use a map (array) as second parameter to effect several attributes at once.

As sais already, its better to bind an event to the click function...

Good luck !
PS alos check removeAttr() : http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/

Answer (score 0):

For events you can bind -

```
$('a[title="name"]').click(function(){
   // Do Stuff here
}
```

For other attributes -

```
$('a[title="name"]').attr('onclick', '');
```